Intuition behind generative methods for imputing missing data
I’m learning different approaches to impute a tabular dataset of mixed continuous and categorical variables, and with data assumed to be missing completely at random. I converted the categorical data using a frequency encoder so everything is either numerical or NaN.
I think the imputation like mean, median,… is too simple and bias-prone. I’m thinking of more sophisticated ways like deterministic and generative.
For deterministic, I tried LightGBM and it’s so intuitively nice. I love it. Basically for each feature with missing data, its non-missing data serves as a regression on the other features and then predicts/imputes the missing data. Lovely.
Now I attempt to use deep learning approaches like AE or GAN. Going through the literature, it seems very possible and very efficient. But the blackbox is hard to follow. For example, for VAE, are we just simply build a VAE model based on the whole tabular data and then “somehow” it can predict/generate/impute the missing data?
I’m still looking into this for clearer explanation but I hope someone who has also attempted to impute tabular data could share some experience.

Fun little question! (+1) I think it is a slightly understudied subject a round VAEs. Please see my answer for more details.

There is a small but fun literature body on how to handle missing data with Variational Autoencoders (VAEs). Some suggest replacing the missing values in data with random values (e.g. McCoy et al. (2018) Variational Autoencoders for Missing Data Imputation with Application to a Simulated Milling Circuit) and making an EM-like procedure. Other approaches use a masking (i.e. missing) matrix $M$ so that the encoder takes both the observed data and the matrix $M$ as input. Then only by observed data are used during the representation learning step and the missing data are "ignored". (e.g. Nazábal et al. (2020) Handling incomplete heterogeneous data using VAEs) Finally there are some works like Collier et al. (2020) VAEs in the Presence of Missing Data which go full-on the idea of modelling the missingness mechanism (MCAR, MAR, NMAR - particularly for MNAR scenarios). They give access to $M$ to both the decoder and the encoder part of the VAE such that it models the missing mechanism itself rather than just use $M$ as a pseudo-indicator variable. Cardoso-Pereira et al. 2020 Missing Image Data Imputation using Variational Autoencoders with Weighted Loss is a bit of middle ground between the two above-mentioned papers as it incorporates a weighted reconstruction loss to give more importance to observed data during training.
So in short, there is no "simply build a VAE model based on the whole tabular data and then “somehow” it can predict/generate/impute the missing data" approach per se. There are a number of different nuisanced approaches. There is a (not very highly cited) review article I haven't read: Reviewing Autoencoders for Missing Data Imputation: Technical Trends, Applications and Outcomes by Cardoso-Pereira et al. (2020) that could be informative in that regard. It will probably be helpful to give a more rounded view of the subject, it really explores not just the algorithms but also the dataset and metrics the report.

First, I'd like to highlight how neural networks usually fall short in tabular settings... for example, enforcing domain constraint is not that easy (consider imputing on-hot encoded features)
However, what you are saying I'd say is ok, at the end of the day you are planning to learn $p(x|x')$, so as long as you build an architecture that can elastically work on such distribution, you should be good to go.
One option is to create a Conditional VAE, and use the conditioning to feed the network of the known features, and use the VAE to learn the sampling.
However, you should also consider why you are doing this. For example, if you then want to learn a classifer, you are interested in $p(y|x)$, and say that $x_i$ is NaN, then the task is $\mathbb{E}[p(y|x)]$. At that point however, you usually optimize the models to have a point estimate, for example with MSe you will get $\mathbb{E}_{p(y|x)}[Y|X]$.
This implies that using generative model, marginalizing over the missing feature, you get $\mathbb{E}_{x_i}[\mathbb{E}_{p(y|x, x_i)}[Y|X, x_i]]$. Now, based on how you model $p(y|x, x_i)$, this might be overly complicated (but do not cite me on this, though I'm sure that for linear model this is overkill).
Nonetheless, the genrative model approach is definitely sound, as long as you pose your problem in the correct way
